# Is it possible to convert a character date to another character date format without using input statement...possible?

Tags: sas

Is there a faster /shorter way to convert character date to another character date format without using an intermediate input statement as done here below...

```
data alpha;
length date $12;
input date $;
cards;
15FEB2014
;
run;

data beta;set alpha;
date_f=put(input(date,date9.),yymmdd10.);
run;
```

Character date:  15FEB2014  --> Character date: 2014-02-15

Thanks

sas_kappel

Comment: mistake in the title it should be understood as 'another character date format'...

Comment: The real question is why would you want to?  (Serious question)

Comment: Second to Robert's comment, if you explained why perhaps an alternative solution could be shown.

Comment: You can move the date_f assignment statement into the previous datastep. Place it between the `input` and `cards` statements. This doesn't remove the input/put function, but removes the intermediate step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is possible, but it's not likely to be easier.

```
data alpha;
  length date $12;
  input date $;
cards;
15FEB2014
;
run;

data beta;set alpha;
  date_f=put(input(date,date9.),yymmdd10.);
  format date_f2 $10.;
  array monnames[12] $ _temporary_ ("JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY","JUN","JUL","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC") ;
  date_f2 = catx('-',substr(date,6,4),put(whichc(substr(date,3,3),of monnames[*]),z2.),substr(date,1,2));
run;
```

I can't think of a simpler way than that without cheating any more than I already am in that.  The `put(input())` method is doing a lot of work behind that small amount of code.

You could also write a direct character format that converted `'01JAN2014'` to `'2014-01-01'`, but you'd have to write every single possible conversion one by one unless I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Interesting code. I am realising  that  the put(input()) method is perhaps the easiest way to achieve my goal. The format procedure would work for the condition given that you have a very limited amount of distinct values to convert.